# overflow: auto doesn't work with images

Tags: html, css

I want a div to contain several images in a single scrollable row. The following code works if i replace the images with a long string, but doesn't work with images.

```
<html>
<div style="overflow: auto">
<img src="a.jpg">
<img src="b.jpg">
<img src="c.jpg">
<img src="d.jpg">
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: sure it does. and the title you gave to describe this is quite bad...please close the `<div>`

Comment: overflow will work when `width` and / or `height` is set. otherwise `div` is 100% width by default - this applies for all block elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work. Maybe [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property is what you're looking for though? See below:

```css
div {
  width: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/400x200">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/400x200">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/400x200">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/400x200">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/400x200">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/400x200">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/400x200">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please set height and width of the div so it will work see the below example

```css
<style>
.auto-div {
    background-color: #00FFFF;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}


</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>


<div class="auto-div">

<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg" /><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg" /><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg" /><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg" /><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg" /><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are not giving any height and width to the div tag so the style overflow: auto is not working for you.

```html
 <div style="width:150px;height:150px;overflow:auto;border:1px solid black">
        <image src="images.jpg"></image>
        <image src="images.jpg"></image>
        <image src="images.jpg"></image>
        <image src="images.jpg"></image>

    </div>
```